# Auditing of actions made via Tivoli Dynamic workload console

Tags: tivoli, tivoli-work-scheduler

In tivoli dynamic workload console how to check which user has run or hold the job

Answer (score 0):

There are audit functionalities on both IWSz and IWSd that can be used to track and discover the author of any change to definitions or plan.

Configuration differs on IWSz and IWSd.

**On IWSd**

The main settings to enable and configure auditing are `enDbAudit`, `enPlanAuditin` and `auditStore` in `optman`. By default it's enabled writing both on DB and on files.

On the console, under Administration -> Auditing Preferences, you can customize if users have to provide additional justification or ticket number for any change they make. Similar information can be optionally provided also on command lines.

The auditing information can be accessed via Reporting, DB queries (using `AUDIT_STORE_RECORDS_V` view), or auditing files.
The same information are also available on the console:

- In *Manage Workload Definitions* as *Recent Activity* or in the *Versions* tab of each object
- In *Monitor Workload* as *Recent Activity* for each object in the plan

More details on [Auditing facilities section in official doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/distr/src_ad/awsadauditoverview.htm)

**On IWSz**

Audit information can be extracted in a report running a batch on z/OS, the information about the JCL sample and interactive menus to generate the report are available [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/zos/src_cust/eqqc1zOSAuditPack.htm)

There are some parameters that affects the information available in the audit reports, the full list is available in the [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/zos/src_cust/eqqc1JTlogdata.htm)

Comment: Thanks Franco for your response

Comment: But I didnot find the Audit Functionality in Tivoli Dynamic Workload Scheduler, can you please provide more info on this how to check which user has action on Deleting/holding/cancelling the jobs or jobstreams

Comment: Do you use IWSz or IWSd?

Comment: Thankyou Franco for the detailed info

Comment: We are using IWSd version 9.3, but as you have mentioned above
under Administration -> Auditing Preferences
I cannot see Auditing Preferences under Administration
I have check all the options in TDWC, but didnot find the Auditing Preferences
I think Auditing Preferences is not enabbled

Comment: Basic auditing was already present in 9.3, but Audit Preferences in DWC, justification, consolidation of FTA audits on the master, have been introduced with 9.4

Comment: Hello Franco,
Thankyou for your comments
I didnot find any audition option in DWC,
Actually I want to check some one  has hold/re-run/cancel the job which user it is
but I am not getiing option to check which user performed what operations on tws job/jobstreams

Comment: On 9.3 you have to look at the audit files on the master or generate an audit report